# Android WebView not refreshing after webpage content changes

Tags: android, android-webview

My Application shows the content of a webpage in a Android webview. 
The webpage is designed by a 3rd party team and as such I have no control on the design or the source code. The webpage shows some kind of animation to begin with and then refreshes with the actual content (normal UI design). However my webview never goes beyond the initial animation.

Please note that I have verified that the webpage loads properly on a browser on the same device. So there is definitely no problem with the Webpage.
Also I have refreshed the webview pro-grammatically after a delay of 5 seconds (On a desktop browser, the webpage takes roughly 1-2 seconds for refreshing the actual content) which should have accounted for the delayed refresh.

Is there any known issue with modern webpages (HTML 5 + CSS3 + JS) that might result them not rendering properly on Android webview ? What can i fallback to ?
Am I missing setting any property on the Webview ?

Below is a snippet of my code  -

```
myWebView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.catalog_view);
WebSettings settings = myWebView.getSettings();
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.homehardware.com.au/catalogue/?category=garden-outdoor");
```

Note : The URL mentioned in teh codeis the actual URL i am trying to load. I have also tried couple of other things, like fiddling with the webview cache mode, UA string etc. but nothing works.

Comment: Add this line "settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);" and check.

Comment: That worked liked charm. I had tried almost all methods and guess i had to try a few more :)

Comment: Are you playing HTML5 storyline ? these are basically videos embedded in html content.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, the website is designed by a 3rd party and as such i am not sure if they are using HTML5 storyline. I have provided the link in my question. Please do check the source code if you are interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the question for future reference for SO explorers, the answer is from the upvoted comment by praveen.

The trick is to use
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true)

Note : although as per my opinion, with HTML5 becoming one of the defacto standards on which modern web pages are based, this setting should by default be enabled on Android webviews (so that webviews by default behave the way modern browsers do)

Comment: How come the storage API is related to the problem?

Answer (score 5):

The below two settings should be there to avoid webview caching to update the page without refresh

```
settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
```

> [webView.loadDataWithBaseURL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))